# Looking for a good SFX library with bare feet on concrete / marble

Tags: library-sound-effects, footsteps, concrete

Doing a short film soon which is purely set in one location but features a lot of footsteps and movement, but struggling to find a library offering enough variety. Think of the locale as a big prison cell with solid concrete floor. All ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

If you struggle to find a suitable library, you can create your own; if you can, try to record the footsteps of a person walking on the film location. Be aware though: it requires some gear (at worst a half-decent smartphone, at best a solid mic and a decent preamp and recorder), a decent sound technician and a decent sound engineer. I won't go into details about the "decent gear": it is covered in other posts on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Sound Dogs returned 2015 hits when I searched on "bare feet". There may be enough in there for your production.  OTOH, you could consider doing a special SFX or "location Foley" recording session.

Ref: http://www.sounddogs.com/extendedsearch.asp?keyword=bare+feet&ddCategory=-1

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of decent effects on Pond5, depending on how much you need. eg. https://www.pond5.com/sound-effects/1/bare-footsteps-concrete.html#1